# Is it possible to create a persisted redux store for each user?

Tags: redux, user-management, redux-persist

I am using Redux-Toolkit together Redux-Persist to store the state in the case the page is refreshed. This works great with one user but how can this be managed with multiple users? If user A signs out and then user B signs in, how can I persist both user's state?

The recommended way is to use only one store, but is it possible to switch between different store instances and storing them with persist?

I couldn't find any similar approach so this thinking might be flawed. A database could be used to store a simple user settings like theming but I wouldn't use it for the entire state.

Comment: Possible, yes, but if a user signs out then typically you'd want to clear out any saved/persisted/etc data associated to them, or at least I think that is what most users of apps expect the behavior to be. The local persisted state should only be a local copy of the ***current*** user. If multiple users are using the same device then you'll likely want to store their data long term server-side, or simply re-fetch/re-derive the client-side state when they log in again. Perhaps you can [edit] to clarify the use case you want?

Comment: I wanted to store the current state of the app for refresh, and also the long term options(theme mode) together inside the persisted store. But I guess it would be better to manage these separated, so the store would only have the current user state and the long term options would be stored with a database like you pointed it out. Thanks.